# How to test python methods that include datetime.now() for different dates?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I have some methods that make use of `datetime.datetime.now()` from the `datetime` library. I want to write unit tests for those methods as if `now()` is several different times (for example, 5th day of the month, 15th day of the month).

For example, let's say I have this method (really just an example, I don't have a method like this)

```
import datetime

def days_left_this_month():
    return 30 - datetime.datetime.now().day
```

I'd want to test that method for the 5th day of the month ie: `days_left_this_month() == 25` if `now()` is on the 5th day of the month.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: freezegun from jmunsch answer looks tailored exactly for this. In the more general case of setting the return value of a function, you patch the function path and setup the mock return value to be just the value you want during your test(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `freezegun`:

```
from freezegun import freeze_time
import datetime
import unittest


@freeze_time("2019-10-05")
def test():
    assert datetime.datetime.now() == datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 05)
```

For example to test `days_left_this_month`:

```
def days_left_this_month():
    return 31 - datetime.datetime.now().day
```

We can:

```
@freeze_time("2019-10-05")
def test():
    assert days_left_this_month() == 26

def test_multiple():
    with freeze_time(x):
        assert days_left_this_month() == y
    with freeze_time(x):
        assert days_left_this_month() == y
    with freeze_time(x):
        assert days_left_this_month() == y
    with freeze_time(x):
        assert days_left_this_month() == y
```

Comment: Thanks, would this work if I'm testing a method within `test()`? IE: ```assert days_left_this_month() == 25```? Also, can I change the time several times throughout the test method?